# Form submits with previous fields values

Tags: jquery, google-maps, submit

The following code is supposed to send an address to Google Maps, get as a reply the latitude and longitude, store them in the proper fields in the form and submit the form.
What actually happens is the alerts appear in the correct order - first the two default values and then the ones received from google, but then two strange things happen: the timeout doesn't happen and the form submits with the default values instead of the ones from google.
Can you please say why?

```
$('#simplr-reg').submit(function(event)
{           
    $("input[name=latitude]").val(9999);    // set default values
    $("input[name=longitude]").val(9999);               
    alert($("input[name=latitude]").val());
    alert($("input[name=longitude]").val());

    codeAddress(function(success){}); //callback from googlemaps    

    setTimeout(function(){
        callback(false); //pass false indicating no/invalid response 
        }, 20000);
});

function codeAddress(callback)
{               
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status)
    {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
        {   
            var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            $("input[name=latitude]").val(latitude); 
            $("input[name=longitude]").val(longitude);

            alert($("input[name=latitude]").val());
            alert($("input[name=longitude]").val());            
        }                   
    });         
}  // end of code address
```

Comment: Two questions: 1) How is `address` defined? 2) What does `callback(false)` do?

Comment: @Alex R., address is defined earlier in the code. You can add `var address = "new york";` at the beginning of the function codeAddress just for this case. I'm not sure about `callback(false)`. Someone showed me how to set a pause and this is how wrote it. My guess is it's doing a pause without calling any function but I could be far from the truth.

Comment: Ok, you should know what `callback(false)` does. The correct signature is `setTimeout(code,millisec,lang)`. Thus, it is correct that the anonymous `callback(false)` is executed after 20 seconds. However, it doesn't seem to be your objective. You are writing the callback incorrectly.

Comment: @Alex R., what I want to do is set a pause so that the google stuff will have enough time (since it's asynchonous) to finish before the form submits. How can I just create a pause without calling any code?

Comment: You don't need to _pause_. Check out my answer below regarding callbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the callback incorrectly, causing your *need* to use `setTimeout`. Also, `$.submit()` function happens **before** the actual submission of the form. That's probably why the value of the inputs reset every time.

Please refer to [.submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) and [.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) and check which one suits your need.

Alternatively, you can opt not to submit the form altogether, and arrive at something like this (not tested):

Have a button so that you can trigger the event:

```
<input type="button" name="submitBtn">
```

When the user clicks this, it will set the values of the inputs:

```
$('#submitBtn').click(function () {
   var address = "new york"; // or an input value
   var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
   geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status)
   {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
        {   
            var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            $("input[name=latitude]").val(latitude); 
            $("input[name=longitude]").val(longitude);      
        }                   
    });         
});
```

No need to set a timeout as the callback function itself will get called once the response has returned. Unless of course, you need the timeout for some other purpose--e.g. `callback(false)` is doing something else.

*Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with the Geocoder API.*

**EDIT:**

If you don't want to edit the HTML, you can instead introduce a variable.

```
var isCallBack = false;

$('#simplr-reg').submit(function(event)
{           
    if (!isCallBack) {
        $("input[name=latitude]").val(9999);    // set default values
        $("input[name=longitude]").val(9999);               
        event.preventDefault();
        codeAddress();
    } else
        isCallBack = false; // may not be required if the page refreshes
});

function codeAddress()
{               
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status)
    {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
        {   
            var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            $("input[name=latitude]").val(latitude); 
            $("input[name=longitude]").val(longitude);

            isCallBack = true;
            $('#simplr-reg').trigger('submit');
        }                   
    });         
}  // end of code address
```

Comment: @Alex R., thanks for the alternative you suggest but I don't want to add any buttons or change the current one since the submitted form is handled by a wordpress plugin. I know the `$.submit()` function happens before the submission of the form. That's how I count on the lat/long fields to be filled with values before the submission of the form. And they do. I just don't understand why they are being reseted.

Comment: @Ash, If the `input`s are part of the `form`, then when the `form` submits, the values get cleared. If you cannot change the html, then going back to your original function, you can add `event.preventDefault()` just before the `submit` closes. This will prevent the form from submitting.

Comment: @Alex R., the user fills the fields in the form, fields such as name, e-mail and address and then hits the submit button. Then, right before the form submits, I need the `submit()` function to send the address to google, get back the lat & long, put them in their fields in the form and then let the form be submitted. So using `event.preventDefault()` will not do what I need. Somehow after the fields got the values from oogle they get the default values again. That's what's important to find out the reason for.

Comment: @Ash, Check out my edited solution. Basically, using `setTimeout` cannot be relied upon if you're using callbacks.

Comment: @Alex R., I tried your edited solution but the second submit doesn't cause the form to submit. Even this simple code doesn't submit: `$('#simplr-reg').submit(function(event) { this.submit(); event.preventDefault(); });`

Comment: @Ash, If you do it like that, you are simply iterating unnecessarily. In my edited solution, try using `$('#simplr-reg').submit()` instead of the `trigger`. Put a breakpoint in that line to make sure that it goes through and confirm that `isCallBack = true;`

Comment: @Alex R., It still wont submit. The short code I gave before was to show you that even the simplest use of `event.preventDefault();` and an inner or second iteration of the `submit()` function doesn't work in my case. I've asked about it in a different question but no one was able to find the problem. This is why I changed direction and tried the way I asked about here - using the original submit but postponing it until the google function finishes.

Comment: @Alex R. , it turns out the second or inner `submit()` did work, they just had a different effect then the original submit because the button's value was not set and the handling php function was dependent on that. Thanks for your help!